# How to create a new master page based on the current regular page?

Tags: adobe-indesign

There are easy ways to take a current style and turn it into a Paragraph Style, Character Style, etc.

Is there any equivalent for Master Pages? I.e. taking the margins etc of an existing regular page, and creating a master page based on them.

All I can find in searches is how to create master pages based on other master pages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Drag a `page` into the `masters` section of the `Pages` panel.

<sup><sub>You can also drag in multiple pages at once.</sub></sup>

[image]