# Is there a proper place to keep unused pages and scraps?

Tags: adobe-indesign

I deleted a page, only to want it back again later.  Then, I moved some page content off the page region and onto the grey area associated with the spread; I know that's cut off with any kind of printing or export.  If we move that element back into the design, I can find which page I left it near and fetch it again.

That is not great, because it doesn't stay in a useful spot, and it doesn't show well against the grey background.

Is there a "bin" or "scrap pages" section that is *meant* for that kind of stuff?  Especially when doing a booklet that must have exactly the right number of pages, I don't want to just add extra pages without having them somehow "officially" part of a chapter that's not active.

What's a good way to do this in InDesign CC 2015?

Comment: pssst.. snippets and libraries: https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/reusing-graphics-text.html

Comment: You could right click anywhere inside the document and deselect "Match pasteboard to theme color" (This was a thing they added in cs6, I believe). **---** For a more localized storage, I sometimes use master pages. Just create a new master page and dump stuff in there. Or if you want the whole page, [you can create a master from a page.](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/61084/2332). The master will obviously not be printed, unless you apply it to some pages.

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate the file and keep it as a backup. Then delete all unwanted stuff from your work file. If you need anything back, just copy it from the backup and "paste in place".